# How many worksheets can be created in an Excel workbook for automation testing?

Tags: excel, selenium, junit, apache-poi, data-driven-tests

I am working on a data driven framework for automating test cases. I use Selenium with Java, Junit, Apachi-Poi etc to create and run my test cases.

Each sheet contains data that I will use for a class (or for a testcase). So now, if I create N testcases then there should be N sheets in a workbook. But I need to know how many sheets can be created in an Excel workbook.

Answer (score 2):

... It depends on the Excel version, but 2007 +, there is no limit other than the amount of available memory:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010073849.aspx#BMworksheetworkbook

Comment: My Lead suggested 255 sheets with 255 columns max is a good idea to have them in my task. I know things are different with companies . I like to know, do companies (ie QA teams) prefer to have more than 255 sheets in a workbook for automation purpose. If it depends on memory size than I have liberty to create as many sheets as possible with each sheet containing testdata (Note: for me a sheet will have data for one testcase).

Comment: ... I don't think there's a hard and fast rule to this - Limiting your workbook to 255 sheets is probably a good idea as far as being able to work with any client and you can very easily just create 2+ workbooks and have them all in 1 directory... It would essentially be the same.

Answer (score 2):

The number of sheets (tabs) is only limited by the available memory you have available. To see information about this (and various other Excel limits) follow these five steps:

1. Ensure you are in an activate session of Excel and press F1
2. Enter "Excel limits" in the Type a question for help text box and press Enter
3. From the Search Results window, click on the Excel specifications and limits hyperlink
4. Show (expand out) the Worksheet and workbook heading
5. Under the Feature field, refer to the Sheets in a workbook heading